# How can I do backward port rebasing?

Tags: git

*Version Control with Git* says:

> You can keep your commit series up-to-date with respect to the master
>   branch by writing the commits so that they are based on commit E
>   rather than B. Because the topic branch needs to be the current
>   branch, you can use either:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout topic
> $ git rebase master or
>
> $ git rebase master topic
> ```
>
> After the rebase operation is complete, the new commit graph resembles
>   Figure 10-13. Using the git rebase command in situations like the one
>   shown in Figure 10-12 is often called **forward porting**. In this
>   example, the topic branch topic has been forward ported to the master
>   branch. There is no magic to a rebase being **a forward** or **a
>   backward port**; both are possible using git rebase.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

What is backward port? How can I do it using `git rebase` command?

Answer (score 1):

Backward port just means that you take a topic branch `topic` that is based on some commit, i.e. `D`, and rebase it on some older commit rather than newer, i.e. `A`.

So, the command would be:

```
git rebase A topic
```

Where `A` is the actual commit hash.

The point that the chapter is trying to make is that git doesn't care where you rebase the topic branch to.

Answer (score 1):

While "backward" refers to rebasing to an *older* commit, it also reflect the practice of "[retrofitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrofitting)", which, in software, is the act of [backporting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backporting)

> The action of taking parts from a newer [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) of a software system or software component and [porting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) them to an older version of the same software. It forms part of the maintenance step in a software development process, and it is commonly used for fixing security issues in older versions of the software and also for providing new features to older versions.

In Git, that "port" can be a backward rebase, but is more often a cherry-pick (because you might already forward-rebase your branch, while having the need to replicate those same patches/commits to an older version of your software, in case of a bug fix)